# C#での独自クラスのリストの操作について

Tags: c#

お世話になります。
C#で下記のコードのように独自のクラスを作り、それをリストに追加しています。

```
public class person(){
public int id {get;set;}
public string name {get;set;}
public int age {get;set;}
}

(中略)

List<person> p = new List<person>();
p.Add(new person(){
id = 1,
name = "テスト",
age = 20,
});

p.Add(new person(){
id = 2,
name = "f",
age = 21,
});

p.Add(new person(){
id = 3,
name = "c",
age = 23,
});

p.Add(new person(){
id = 4,
name = "サンプル",
age = 20,
});
```

このようなリストで次のような操作を行いたいのですが、何かよい方法はないでしょうか。

- リストから「name」部分を取り出して、文字列の配列にする。
  「p.ToArray();」ではエラーになるため、現在は下記のような感じでforeachで回していますが、簡単な方法があれば、教えてください。

  ```
  List<string> name_list = new List<string>();
  foreach (person i in p){
  name_list.Add(i.name);
  }
  name_list.ToArray();
  ```
- 作成したリストを「name」をキーにして昇順にソートしたいのですが、どうしたらいいでしょうか。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

簡単かどうかは疑問ですが、LINQの <del>[SelectManyメソッド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) と</del> [Selectメソッド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) を使えば1行で出来ます。
旧冗長な回答：
<del>string[] name_list = new[] { p }.SelectMany(list => list.Select(entry => entry.name)).ToArray();</del>

⇒生兵法は怪我の元ですね。少ない経験で応用しようとしてイマイチな内容でした。@mok2pok さん回答のように以下にしたかったのですが。

```
string[] name_list = p.Select(entry => entry.name).ToArray();
```

ソートの方は、リスト自身をソートするなら、Listクラスの [Sortメソッド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.8) を：

```
p.Sort((a, b) => string.Compare(a.name, b.name));
```

元のリストはそのままにして、ソートした結果を別に受け取るならLINQの [OrderByメソッド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8) を使うのが良いようです：

```
List<person> q = p.OrderBy(n => n.name).ToList();
```

`name`の抽出・文字列配列化と、リストを`name`でソートするのは別々の要求と考えました。

参考
[【C#】自作クラスのListのソート](https://qiita.com/tetsu8/items/96b8b889c57eb55125d1)
[自作クラスによる配列をソート（並べ替え）するには？（LINQ版）［3.5、C#、VB］](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/fdotnet/dotnettips/880orderby/orderby.html)
[C#でラジオボタンの複数のグループボックスのチェック状態を全て取得したいです。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/56795/26370)

Comment: サンプルコードありがとうございます。うまくいきました。

Answer (score 2):

昇順にソートされた`name`文字列の配列がほしいなら、

```
string[] array = p
    .Select(e => e.name)    // nameだけ取り出して
    .OrderBy(name => name)  // ソートして
    .ToArray();             // 配列に変換
```

元のリスト`p`を`name`で昇順ソートした新しいListが欲しい（元の`p`はソートされない）なら、

```
List<person> sortedList = p
    .OrderBy(e => e.name)  // nameでソートして
    .ToList();             // Listに変換
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。ソートのあたりはあまり詳しくなかったので、コメントをつけていただいて助かりました。

Answer (score 0):

リストから「name」部分を取り出して、文字列の配列にする簡単な方法は、ちょっとわかりませんが。
自作クラスのソート方法は、下記を参考にしてみてください。
https://qiita.com/tetsu8/items/96b8b889c57eb55125d1

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考ページに私がやりたかったことがそのまま書いてありました。もうちょっとちゃんと調べればよかったですね。